# Connect two div elements using a line in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Some context on the use case:

There is a tree on left side and right side, and each tree has several nodes. When user selects say node A on left hand side tree, user needs to see a connection between that node and node A on the right hand side tree. So I need to create a visual representation of this in react. In fact one node on LHS can be connected to multiple other nodes on RHS and vice versa.

I checked html canvas, but was wondering if there is a much simpler way to do this in react.

[image]

Comment: I found this package[react-connected](https://github.com/emersonlaurentino/react-connect-elements) here a demo [sandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-dew-ifkv6?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: I'm looking for implementation details. Would like to avoid third party libraries.

Comment: Ok so you can have a look to the source code in the repository of react-connected